# Is it necessary to check the return value of spawn.send in pexpect?

Tags: python, string, sockets, pexpect

Is it necessary to check the return value of `send` in pexpect?

The implementation of `spawn.send(s)` is using something like:

```
c = os.write(self.child_fd, s)
return c
```

Where the number of bytes are returned.  There is also a convenience function:

```
def sendline(self, s=''):
    """This is like send(), but it adds a line feed (os.linesep). This
    returns the number of bytes written. """
    n = self.send(s)
    n = n + self.send (os.linesep)
    return n
```

Which behaves similar.  Unlike `telnetlib`, there does not seem to be any helper function like `sendall` which continuously checks the number of bytes written and retries if necessary until the whole message is transmitted.

In pexpect example code online, people don't seem to bother checking the return value of send .. is this unnecessary for some reason?  Is it ever possible that the number of bytes sent is less than expected?

Comment: Since you are relying on the OS to handle IPC for you, and the buffers used for that tend to be large, with little delay, the odds of a very short string being not entirely written are pretty low, so people get away with not actually verifying the results.  On some systems, it might be possible for the number of bytes sent to be less than all of them, but it is not generally a problem.